# PHP Switch content in while

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a standard Mysqli/php code that echo a list of items.

So lets say that a user has chosen to edit a specified product. The products is being
printet in a while loop. How do i switch content in only ex. product 9 if there is printed 100 products in a while loop?

All the products is in a Div.

Some code ex:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_name, item_id FROM items");
while($items = $query->fetch_assoc()){

  echo $items['item_name'];
  echo '<a href="" onclick="switch content of only the single product that has been chosen">Edit me</a>'

}
```

Comment: `echo '<a href="#" onclick="return switchproduct(\'' . $items["item_id"] . '\');">Edit me</a>'`

Comment: Please don't use intrusive javascript [i.e. `onclick` attribute]. Use a `data-id` attribute, then rely on it when you click on any link.

Comment: Data-id is in fact a good idea! But how do I operate with that? :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator for this:

```
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT item_name, item_id FROM items");
while($items = $query->fetch_assoc())
{   
    $clickEvent = ($items['item_id'] == 9) ? 'for id 9' : 'for others';
    echo $items['item_name'];
    echo '<a href="" onclick="'.$clickEvent.'">Edit me</a>'
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your suggestion. the value 9 need's to be dynamic though? Can i do something like this $items['item_id'] == $_GET['item_id'] (get item id that has been selected from a url or is there a better dynamic solution?)

Comment: But is it possible to do it more dynamicly so that the page dosen't have to reaload? Could it bee in fact a good idea to send an id into data-id and then somehow send it to ajax/jquery and let jquery switch the content for the chosen product? :)

Comment: Yes, you would have to use AJAX. Adding it as a `data` attribute and then using jQuery is probably your best bet.

Comment: But how do i make sure that i switch the right div/content in jquery?

Comment: Add a class name to the relevant `div`?